# implementing if-then-elif-then-else in jax

Tags: python, jax, cudnn

I'm just starting to use JAX, and I wonder—what would be the right way to implement if-then-elif-then-else in JAX/Python? For example, given input arrays: `n = [5, 4, 3, 2]` and `k = [3, 3, 3, 3]`, I need to implement the following pseudo-code:

```py
def n_choose_k_safe(n, k):
    r = jnp.empty(4)
    for i in range(4):
        if n[i] < k[i]:
            r[i] = 0
        elif n[i] == k[i]:
            r[i] = 1
        else:
            r[i] = func_nchoosek(n[i], k[i])
    return r
```

There are so many choices like `vmap`, `lax.select`, `lax.where`, `jax.cond`, `lax.fori_loop`, etc., so that it is hard to decide on specific combinations of the utilities to use. By the way, `k` can be a scalar (if that makes it simpler).

Answer (score 4):

There's a slightly more compact way to express the solution in Valentin's answer, using [`jax.numpy.select`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.select.html):

```py
def n_choose_k_safe(n, k):
  return jnp.select(condlist=[n > k, n == k],
                    choicelist=[jnp.vectorize(func_nchoosek)(n, k), 1],
                    default=0)
```

For input arrays of length 4, this should return the same result as your original code, assuming `func_nchoosek` is compatible with `jax.vmap`. Using `vectorize` here in place of `vmap` will make the function also compatible with scalar inputs for `k`, without having to manually set the `in_axes` argument.

Comment: Yes, jnp.select worked as well as Valentin's jnp.where. I did not notice difference in performance, but code became smaller since I was able to keep scalar variants of the functions only. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

First you can vectorize the function `func_nchoosek` to accept `n` and `k` as flat vectors (we assume that `func_nchoosek` accepts inputs of shape (1, ) otherwise it should be necessary to do so first of all) then:

```py
func_nchoosek_vect = jax.vmap(func_nchoosek, (0, 0), 0)
```

Now `func_nchoosek_vect([n1, n2, ...], [k1, k2, ...]) = [func_nchoosek(n1, k1), func_nchoosek(n2, k2), ...]` the operation are done element-wise (similar to `zip`).

If `k` is a single scalar, you can use this instead:

```py
func_nchoosek_vect = jax.vmap(func_nchoosek, (0, None), 0)
```

Now you can use the function `jnp.where` to select the data you want. It is like `lax.select` but more flexible. The function is compatible with jit compilation and preserve gradients (under some further assumptions) as long as you use it with 3 arguments (to have deterministic shapes).

```py
def n_choose_k_safe(n: jnp.array, k: jnp.array) -> jnp.array:
  """Choose k among n with safety."""
  r = jnp.where(n > k, func_nchoosek_vect(n, k), -1)
  r = jnp.where(n == k, 1, r)
  r = jnp.where(n < k, 0, r)
  return r
```

Comment: Using select does have the benefit of a single static array operation.

Comment: the jnp.where worked like a charm! Ty Valentin! i will try jnp.select next